# Cannot break excel link to broken connection

Tags: microsoft-excel, connection

I have a file and I cannot seem to find where the connection is.  I have look in the following places:

- Data>>Connections
- Conditional formatting
- Searches for "[" and ".xl"
- Data Validation, but there is none
- All pivot tables data sources have been checked
- Named ranges
- File >> Info >> Related documents

Any other suggestions that I can use to find where this link is?

Photo of error message:
[image]

Comment: Maybe its contained in a macro? Go to the view, on the bar, and select macros to see if there are any.

Comment: @LevenTech: If an image is already on i.stack.imgur.com, you don't need to download and re-upload it — just edit the markdown.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer from other thread, (posted a community wiki).*

Here's a solution that has been very reliable for me:

1. Change the file extension of your .xlsx file to .zip
2. Unzip this zip in a new folder
3. List item Using Explorer, in that folder,    search for the name in the file CONTENTS.

**Note:** Sometimes the name is written in URL format, e.g., %20 instead of spaces, so you might consider using a simplified string that is found only in the problematic file. I used last word of the filename + .xlsx.

4. It will probably return sheetN.xml as a result. This is the file corresponding to your problematic sheet, where N is the number of the problematic sheet in the order they are displayed. Open it in a text editor such as Notepad.
5. Find the search string and look at the code around it; it should point you to some cell references that you can lookup in the problematic sheet.

**Note:** As pointed out before, it could also be in Conditional Formatting or Data Validation.

Source: [/719931/how-to-find-broken-links-in-excel-that-cant-be-broken-with-break-links/](https://superuser.com/a/1134500/465365)